# Pass the char* directly to printf

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char s[]="sfksfls\n";
void main()
{
        printf(s);

}
```

Why it can work? I just input the char pointer to printf

Comment: Doing that is a really bad idea, btw. What if `s` points to a string like `"foo %d bar"`? Use `fputs(s, stdout);` to print just a string.

Comment: It can work. You can even add a *shift-state* as an integer before `s` to tell `printif` which character to begin output with. But it isn't wise to do ti that way, and it makes code much more difficult to read and maintain. Since you have a string in an array, simply us the `"%s"` *format conversion-specifier* to output the contents of `s`. Doing so provides access to all modifiers available, (e.g. *field-width* modifier, padding and preservation of space for signed values, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

A string literal in C is a pointer to `const char`. `printf` [takes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) a pointer to `const char` (plus an optional list of additional arguments). Passing it directly or through a variable makes no difference, a pointer is a pointer, it's just a number.

Comment: Except here we do not have a pointer to a *string literal*, we have an array that was initialized using a *string literal*, but for all relevant purpose here is just an array containing a string.